# How to make custom 2D shapes to be extruded later?

Tags: modeling

I'm coming from AutoDesk Inventor, and so far I like Blender a good amount. But one question is, can you make custom shapes with lines like you would in a 2D sketch in Inventor?

**Edit:** Sorry, I wasn't specific enough about making a 2D sketch in Inventor.

So basically a 2D sketch can be placed on an xy,xz,yz plane or on a solid plane from another shape. In this instance, I'm looking for a way to make it on a plane.

When you make a 2D sketch, you are -like implied- locked to creating onto a 2D plane, while you are in that mode you are able to use lines, arcs, points, rectangles, etc to create a 2D shape which then after you are done with that, can make a 3d shape by either extruding, revolving, etc.

I was asking if there is a way to do something like that in Blender

[image: Making a shape in with a 2D Sketch (Not my picture)]

[image: Extruding a 2D rectangle (also not my picture)]

Comment: Could you post an example or two? Not everyone is familiar with 2d sketch 
 in Inventor

Comment: Blender has Bezier Curve objects, which can be set to *3D* or *2D* type, essentially achieving the constraint to a 2D plane with the later. You can then extrude said curves, sweep them along a path, or revolve/screw them. Have in mind that unless you convert to a mesh afterwards there is not much more you can do with the curves though. Editing tools are also severely lacking, so you may want to draw them elsewhere and import either as SVG or DXF.